# batch file import of .sql files to mariadb fails

Tags: mysql, batch-file, cmd, mariadb

I wrote a batch file to import a number of .sql backup files into the latest version of the mariadb database:

```
for %%i in (./*.sql) do mysql -u root --password=xxx newgpn_20180701^<%%i
```

When I run the batch file in the windows cmd line I get an error like this:

> ```
> C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.2\bin>for %i in (./*.sql) do mysql -u root  --password=xxx newgpn_20180701<%i
>
> C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.2\bin>mysql -u root --password=xxx newgpn_20180701<ad_keywords2.sql
>
> ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database
> 'newgpn_20180701<ad_keywords2.sql'`
> ```

But if I copy and paste the output directly into the cmd line it works fine e.g.

```
mysql -u root --password=xxx newgpn_20180701<ad_keywords2.sql
```

How can I get the batch file to iterate through all the .sql files in the directory and import them into the database?

Comment: Don't escape the redirection `<` remove the caret `^`

Comment: yes, it was the caret that was causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\`, not `/` in cmd.

Won't `*.sql` suffice instead of `.\*.sql`?

Put a space before `<` to give cmd a chance to see that it is supposed to interpret it.

Comment: There is no space required before `<` to be recognised, it just must not be escaped...